# set multiple `<input>' fields using a variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Multiple input fields set value using variable called multiplier. Each input I added new custom attribute called my_value to calculated based on 3 drop-down and target table with corresponding values. I can calculate the each input correctly and writes on SPAN.

However I have two issue or bug how can I resolve it? 1. I tried to set the input value with variable multiplier so when I select drop-down I see the value from corresponding table displays on input value it is shows on console log tried below code it does not set INPUT value only to test one Id it did not work, what is wrong?

```
$('#Cherry').val(multiplier);
```

or use for all inputs this below dont work, what is wrong?

```
$("input[type='number']") =multiplier;
```

I could not set inputs.

Grand Total shows "NaN" if I set input value with default value and use below line grand total works fine (  )

```
result.text($(this).val() * multiplier);
```

If I remove all Value from input set custom attribute my_value ="40" it calculates each input but Grand Total shows NaN

```
result.text($(this).attr("my_value") * multiplier);

<input id="Cherry" name="Cherry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" my_value ="40" readonly="true"/>
```

**The demo jsfiddler link: https://jsfiddle.net/erkindunya/L3d4j8hv/1/**

Comment: `$("input[type='number']") =multiplier;` is not how jQuery works.

Comment: Maybe you should show all your code. What is `multiplier`? If you have NaN than something is not a number. So check to see if you have a value before you use it? It would be a lot easier to answer with the actual code.

Comment: @epascarello, this is fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/erkindunya/L3d4j8hv/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up your variable assignment:

```
var multiplier = $('input[type="number"]');
```

Comment: Fixed @epascarello

Comment: added the above line, all become NaN?

Comment: as I already declared the variable ,              var multiplier = $(
                `table#${tableToUse} tbody > tr[product='${currentProductId}'] > td[projectValue='${projectValue}']`
            ).text();  I just need assigned it to input value